# Как вывести выбор раскладки при печати?

Tags: javascript

По нажатию на кнопку - выполняю window.print();
Проблема такая, в окне печати нет выбора раскладки (книжная, альбомная) и все печатается как книжное. При этом если нажму ctrl+p то выбора раскладки то же нет, но если я жму ctrl + p например на стак оверфлоу - выбор раскладки есть.
Как вывести этот выбор?

Comment: раскладка это у клавиатуры. при печати - ориентация листа.

Comment: ну у меня когда я жму на ctrl + p написано раскладка

Answer (score 2):

За все что происходив в окне настроек печати отвечает браузер. Вы не можете этим управлять. Можно только указать значение по умолчанию с помощью стилей

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => window.print());
```

```css
@media print {
  @page {
    size: landscape;
  }
}
```

```html
<button>print</button>
```

Comment: а почему тогда браузер именно у меня на сайте скрывает выбор?

Comment: Слишком мало информации чтобы ответить на этот вопрос.